# Pattern for email or telephone number

Tags: regex, html

I have problem with regular expression in pattern for telephon number OR email

Code:

```
<input class="form__input" type="text" name="phone-or-email" placeholder="Telephone or email" pattern="^[0-9]{9}$ || [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}" title="Telephone or email" required="required">
```

Pattern:

```
pattern="^[0-9]{9} || [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$
```

telephone regular expression: `^[0-9]{9,12}$` - it's enough for me

email regular expression:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}
```

it's ok email regular expression for me

Above code doesn't work :(

I would like have one input and one pattern for telephone number and email address

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
pattern="^([0-9]{9})|([A-Za-z0-9._%\+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})$"
```

With regular expressions you use a single "|" to represent OR. I also put telephone pattern and email pattern between parenthesis, so it would accept the telephone pattern or the email.

Comment: You're not escaping + and - signs?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter sender mobile no..." type="text"   pattern="[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}|[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="Please enter valid mobile number" required>
```

In my case above pattern is validating email and phone (starting from 6, 7, 8 or  9) as per Indian standard mobile number